# how to write unit test case for rest WS

Tags: java

I am new for writing unit testcases, i want to know how to write a unit test case for restful web service resource class, which contains GET and POST methods. It will be great if anybody can help me

Comment: What REST framework are you using?  Are you doing this via an integration test suite or via a REST test suite?

Answer (score 2):

It will help you

[JUnit Testing REST Services](http://java.dzone.com/articles/junit-testing-rest-services) [Krishna Prasad's Article](http://java.dzone.com/users/praskrishna)